# ASP.NET C# - select dropdown list not choosing correct value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a basic application using ASP.NET MVC. I have a select dropdown with three text values, blank, "Yes, I'll be there", "No, I can't come". I would like the option value 'true' to be registered by the GuestResponse object in the controller when the "Yes I'll be there" option in the form is submitted, but at the moment it's only coming through as "null". Have I set up the form correctly, and is it sensible to use a boolean type in the model?

GuestResponse.cs (model)

```
    public class GuestResponse
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public bool? WillAttend { get; set; }
    }
```

RSVPForm.cshtml

```
    <form method="post" action="/Home/RsvpForm">
        <div class="form-group">
        <p>
            <label for="Name">Your name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
        </p>
        </div>
        <p>
            <label for="Email">Your email:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Phone">Your phone:</label>
            <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>
                Will you attend?
            </label>
            <select asp-for="WillAttend">
                <option value="Choose an option"></option>
                <option value="true">Yes, I'll be there</option>
                <option value="false">No, I can't come</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <button type="submit">Submit RSVP</button>

    </form>
```

HomeController.cs

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult RsvpForm(GuestResponse guestResponse)
        {
            Repository.AddResponse(guestResponse); // "WillAttend" should return true here.
            return View("Thanks", guestResponse);
        }
        public ViewResult ListResponses()
        {
            return View(Repository.Responses.Where(r => r.WillAttend == true));
        }
    }
```

Thanks.cshtml (the Thanks page)

```
      @{
        Layout = null;
    }
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Thanks</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <h1>Thank you, @Model.Name!</h1>
            @if (Model.WillAttend == true) {
                @:It's great that you're coming. The drinks are already in the fridge!
            } else {
                @:Sorry to hear that you can't make it, but thanks for letting us know.
            }
        </p>
        <p>Click @Html.ActionLink("here", "ListResponses") to see who is coming. </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks,

Regards,

Robert

London, UK

Comment: value="Choose an option" is not a bool. Maybe <option value="">Choose an option</option>

Comment: Try in options WillAttend set values to True, False

Answer (score 1):

You can also use name attribute to send value to controller.

```
<select name="WillAttend">
                <option value="Choose an option"></option>
                <option value="true">Yes, I'll be there</option>
                <option value="false">No, I can't come</option>
            </select>
```